# spark execute column values as sql queries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Dataframe, where one of the column has query strings representing calculations to be done using other columns.

```
val aSeq = Seq(
(1,10,10,10,"avg(c2)"), 
(2,20,20,20,"sum(c1)"), 
(3,30,30,30,"count(id)"),
(4,40,40,40,"(avg(c1)+avg(c2))"), 
(5,50,50,50,"(avg(c3)+avg(c1))")
)

val df = aSeq.toDF("id","c1","c2","c3","calc")
df.show()

+---+---+---+---+--------------------+
| id| c1| c2| c3|                calc|
+---+---+---+---+--------------------+
|  1| 10| 10| 10|             avg(c2)|
|  2| 20| 20| 20|             sum(c1)|
|  3| 30| 30| 30|           count(id)|
|  4| 40| 40| 40|   (avg(c1)+avg(c2))|
|  5| 50| 50| 50|   (avg(c3)+avg(c1))|
+---+---+---+---+--------------------+
```

Is it possible to compute another column that would contain values from these calculations? I am happy to provide more info if needed. Thank you for any input, pointers...

Comment: I don't think `sum(avg(c1)+avg(c2))` is a valid example because of nested aggregation functions. I believe you wanted to write just `(avg(c1)+avg(c2))`

Answer (score 1):

[selectExpr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#selectExpr(exprs:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) can be used to evaluate an SQL expression for a dataset:

```scala
df.select("calc").as[String].collect().foreach{ c =>
  val result = df.selectExpr(c).as[Double].head()
  println("%-17s --> %3.1f".format(c, result))
}
```

prints

```
avg(c2)           --> 30,0
sum(c1)           --> 150,0
count(id)         --> 5,0
(avg(c1)+avg(c2)) --> 60,0
(avg(c3)+avg(c1)) --> 60,0
```

To speed up the computation, the `calc` column could be collected into a [parallel collection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html). The result will probably be printed in a different order:

```scala
df.select("calc").as[String].collect().par.foreach{ c =>
 [same as above]
}
```

I understand the question that the operation in column `calc` should operate on the whole dataframe, not only on the row of which it is part of.

Comment: Thanks. It would seem, for large number of rows, `collect()` could cause issues, but I will give it a try.

Comment: @iamauser to trigger the execution of an sql statement, you have to have this statement on the driver. How many (different) statements do you want to execute?